# Eddystone-URL attachments

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone, bluetooth-gatt, eddystone-url

according to the image below, is it fair to say that Eddystone-URL beacons cannot be associated with attachments((with google beacon platform, even if deprecated)) because it does not have an ID identifier in the frame? the UUID acts only at the GAP level of the protocol stack
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWEMo.png)

Answer (score 0):

The old Google Beacon Platform (for which Google announced a shut down date of April 1, 2021) [included a registration endpoint](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register) which would allow you to register the beacon with their servers.  One of the benefits of this server registration was to allow you to attach data on the server-side, so that when the beacons were detected by Google Play Services, the attachments would be downloaded and made available through the API.

This **did** work with Eddystone-URL, because the identifier payload used to register the beacon was simply a sequence of bytes.  In the case of Eddystone-URL, you would register the bytes of the compressed URL (using Google's Eddystone-URL compression scheme).  The registered bytes were Base64 encoded, so it didn't matter that they were binary data. You simply set the type to EDDYSTONE which covered both the typical EDDYSTONE-UID and less commonly registered EDDYSTONE-URL.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/AdvertisedId) for more info on the way the AdvertiseId was registered.

Comment: because then on the official google documentation( https://developers.google.com/beacons/get-started ) they write "When using this frame type, you cannot register the beacon with Google. Once you have provisioned the beacon, no further steps are required."  ? (in the step Configure your beacons)

Comment: Have you tried it?  In my experience, despite that statement, registration of Eddystone-URL beacon identifiers been allowed in the past.  Sometimes policies and enforcement are not the same.